# Manually Sorting Strings in Column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, columnsorting

I would like to sort these strings in this column in my dataframe. I want to sort by income either lowest to high or high to low - doesn't matter.

Minimal Reproducible Sample

```
    K_INCOME    COFFEE_CONSUMER_CATEGORY    HHID_COUNT
1    100,000− 124,999   retained    154022
12   125,000− 149,999   retained    82124
14   15,000− 19,999 retained    26965
10   150,000− 199,999   retained    77617
9    20,000− 29,999 retained    65817
0    200,000− 249,999   retained    36755
7    250,000− 399,999   retained    21755
3    30,000− 39,999 retained    87054
2    40,000− 49,999 retained    110710
8    400,000− 499,999   retained    3493
11   50,000− 59,999 retained    130240
5    60,000− 74,999 retained    168661
13   75,000− 99,999 retained    242603
4   Less than $15,000   retained    58331
15  More than $500,000  retained    9694
6   None    retained    130015
```

[image]

I tried income_`df_sorted = income_df.sort_values(by=['K_INCOME'])`
income_df_sorted but it returns the below.

[image]

I tried Series has a replace method to do this:

```
s = income_df['K_INCOME'].replace({'None':0, 'Less than $15,000':1, '15,000− 19,999':2})
s.sort_values()
```

...but got this type error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Any ideas on how to sort by income level? Ideally, I do not have to try to convert to integers because they are a range and I need to keep as string on the larger database.

(I need to sort so I can plot income low to high, or high to low.)

update: desired output like this

[image]

[image]

Thanks!
G

Comment: no screengrabs please, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have added the data above.

Comment: For me the logic is not quite clear. For example should someone earning more than 50,000 be higher or lower to somebody earning 60,000-70,000. Etc. Or is it okay to define that somebody who earns less than 20,000 just earns 20,000?

Comment: Ideally, its sorted by income range ex. less than $15k, $15-20k, 20-30K, 30,40k etc.

Comment: Still the question in which group is somebody with 18,000-27,000 or are the steps for granted?

Comment: Those are already assigned to a group. That data above is the exact data aggregated already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i stated in my comment i was not sure how to rank the income. For the sorting i just defined that somebody who earns more then 50 earns 51 and somebody whou earns less than 50 earns 49. On the rest i took the upper income limit. So i used regular expressions to find if somebody earns less or more and set a correction factor. After that splitted and the connected the string to get the income as string. Before returning i cast the string into a integer and add the correctional factor.

```
def calcIncome(string):

    # value is a correction factor for the income
    value = 0
    if re.search("Less than.*", string) != None:
        value = -1
    elif re.search("More than.*", string) != None:
        value = 1

    #extract highest income
    stringLst = re.split('\$|-', string)
    highIncomeLst = stringLst[len(stringLst) - 1].split(',')
    income = ''

    for i in highIncomeLst:
        income += i

    return int(income) + value

sampleDf = pd.DataFrame({'income': ['Less than 3,000', '3000-5000'],
               'B': [21, 32],
            'C': ['a', 'b']})
sampleDf.dropna(subset=['income'], inplace=True)
sampleDf['sorting_income'] = sampleDf.apply(lambda row: calcIncome(row['income']), axis=1)
print(sampleDf.sort_values(by=['sorting_income']))
```

Maybe in the final version you want to drop the new column. You can use something like:
`sampleDF.drop(['sorting_income'], axis=1, inplace=True)`

**On your histogram update**
The principle stays the same. Wirte a function which returns a group for a given income. Like return 0 for less than 15 etc.. And than use the df.apply method like given. To answer more precisely i need to know if the steps are always the same and some information about your desired logic. In which group shold i put somebody earning less than 50. In all lower groups or in the nearest to 50 or in the lowest.

Comment: Thanks moritz. I tried your code with these adjustments 

`income_df['sorting_income'] = income_df.apply(lambda row: calcIncome(row['K_INCOME']), axis=1)
print(income_df.sort_values(by=['sorting_income']))`

but received this error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$249999'`

Comment: Yes sorry overlooked the $-sign in front of the more/less numbers. Just correct the split argument in 
```stringLst = re.split('\$|-', string). ```
 I will correct it in the answer.

Comment: And i also saw now that you have None values as well. You can drop rows with None values with:

 sampleDf.dropna(subset=['income'], inplace=True) 

I also add this to the answer.

Comment: Excellent thank you! That makes sense to me how you did this. clever